# Web service https status code 404

Tags: java, web-services, https

I have a problem with a web service under https protocol, if I use the same web service via http protocol the result is ok.

I have been used the mkyong tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

and I have the error
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 404: Not Found

If I download the certificate and import via keytool I have the same error.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 404 means you're connecting to the server, but there is no content at the path you requested. Either you're passing the wrong URL, or the server is misconfigured and not presenting any content.

Comment: I think so, but the same url works fine in SoapUI and if I open the URL in web browser render the xml ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was found in wsdl definition.
at the end od definition:

```
<wsdl:service name="wsname">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:wsnameSoapBinding" name="wsnamePort">
        <soap:address location="locationVariable"/>     
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

where locationVariable is the direction WITH https.
In my case the location variable had the direction witn http